# Разрешить пользователю создание сырых сокетов

Tags: linux, сокеты

Есть программа запускаемая в скрипте которая создает сырые сокеты, есть ли возможность указать в системе разрешить создание сырых сокетов пользователю? Если нет то как запустить эту программу от суперпользователя в скрипте запускаемом от простого пользователя

Comment: Если программа ничего потенциально вредоносного не сделает, сделайте владельцем програмы рута (chown root программа) и поставьте suid бит на нее `chmod u+s программа` после чего она вне зависимости от того кто ее запустил будет выполнятся с правами рута

Comment: Спасибо, но дело в том что это тестовая программа, которая каждый раз компилируется и запускается в системе автоматической сборки

Comment: тогда поправьте скрипты которые ее запускают, что бы запускали через sudo. В /etc/sudoers указать что эту программу запускать без запроса пароля рута

Comment: возможно, поможет [совет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772068/raw-socket-access-as-normal-user-on-linux-2-4#comment18398572_9772141) изменить и проверить suid в вашей программе.

Comment: @Mike, *без запроса пароля рута* — почему именно root-а? по умолчанию запрашивается пароль текущего пользователя (да, можно использовать директивы rootpw, runaspw или targetpw, но по умолчанию они отключены).

Comment: варинтов «что-то разрешить» несколько, но к описанной ситуации, по-моему, подходит только то, что предложил @Mike. Mike, оформите, пожалуйста, ваше предложение в виде ответа.